# Grouping objects by date range in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

In `models.py` we have:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Contract(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_start = modelsDateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    date_end = modelsDateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digit=20, decimal_places=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

In the template I want to see the monthly table for the summed contract's prices. So for the contracts query set like:

```
<QuerySet[
  {'company__name': 'Nike', 'date_start': datetime.date(2010, 10, 1), 'date_end': datetime.date(2015, 7, 15), 'price': Decimal('100')},
  {'company__name': 'Reebok', 'date_start': datetime.date(2008, 5, 1), 'date_end': datetime.date(2015, 2, 23), 'price': Decimal('100')}
]
```

In the template for selected year 2015 the data are like:

```
jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
200  200  100  100  100  100  100   0    0    0    0    0
```

since Nike's contract is valid through all months of 2015 and Reebok's contract only until July. Can somebody help me with the view and the template for this task?

Comment: Sorting by a *range* is a bit underspecified, since this contains two elements. Do you want to sort on `date_start` first, and in case of an *tie* on `date_end`, if not what way?

Comment: Furthermore it is not clear to me what you want to display... You want to "sum" per month the elements in range?

Comment: yes, sum of prices for the contract objects if thier date range includes the month.